# AG_E_PARSER_BAD_TYPE error when using DataForm control in Prism/silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight-3.0, prism, dataform

I'm using prism and SL3, as soon as I drop a DataForm Control in any modules, I get this error:

```
AG_E_PARSER_BAD_TYPE [Line: 6 Position: 31]
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri 
  resourceLocator)
at HelloWorldModule.Views.HelloWorldView.InitializeComponent()
at HelloWorldModule.Views.HelloWorldView..ctor()
```

I don't get this error if I drop the DataForm control in my Shell.xaml, only if I drop in any views in the modules. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add Microsoft.Windows.Controls to your ModuleManifest.xaml..

Comment: Yes, i have had the same problem. ValidationSummary is defined in System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input assembly. If you are using Prism, then its not enough just to add this assembly reference to class library that is using ValidationSummary, but also you have to add the same reference to your Shell Silverlight project (main SL project where your bootstrapper is located)

Answer (score 1):

Yes...you need to add reference of the dll. It worked for me.